# List that grows upwards (not downward) inside a div, then scrolls

Tags: css, list, scroll, html

I want to have a list grow upwards (not downward) inside a div. Then to scroll the list within that div when there are too many `li` items. Is this combination possible?

The scrolling is easy - fix the height of the div and set the style of that div to `overflow-y: scroll;`

The bottom vertical aligned li was tricky and I chose the simplest solution which was to style the containing div as `position: relative;` and the ul within as `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`

But I want both behaviours.  Unfortunately achieving the bottom vertical aligned li breaks the scrolling.  Or rather, the scrolling happens but I can't drag scroll with the mouse anymore - the scrollbar doesn't appear either.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tcab/Am3uL/

Here is my html

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>six</li>
        <li>five</li>
        <li>four</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here are the relevant styles

```
div.scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.bottomalign_ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.bottomalign {
    position: relative;
}
```

Basically I want to apply all three styles at once - and get the desired effect.

```
$('div').addClass('bottomalign');
$('ul').addClass('bottomalign_ul');
$('div').height(100);
$('div').addClass('scroll');
```

Though this sort of works, the list is merely clipped within the div and I can't scroll it with the mouse anymore.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with you making the ul elements absolute.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling that I have two CSS directives that are 'fighting' each other.  But what is the solution?  I want a HP RPN (reverse polish notation) style calculator stack that grows upwards, yet allows scrolling with the mouse when needed?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to always scroll to bottom when you load the list. So it looks as if its growing bottom up. Is that right? If so check the following solution

[dive bottom up scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up)

**Edit:**

I slightly modified following bits of your fiddle and got scroll bar to bottom in scenario 'both'

css:

```
.bottomalign_ul {
    position: absolute;    
 }
```

JQuery:

```
function scroll() {
    $('div').height(100);
    $('div').addClass('scroll');
    $('div').scrollTop(200);
}
```

Comment: I want to emulate a RPN calculator stack that grows upwards as you enter numbers and strings onto the stack.  Remember the way HP calculators worked?  New entries push onto the stack at the bottom. I also want to be able to swipe/mouse drag to scroll through the previous entries that have scrolled off the screen.  Yes, when you enter a fresh number the stack will typically scroll to the bottom again to show it.

Comment: I think @voddy has the right idea. Because in JQuery you can append elements to the bottom, then use the scroll method to make sure it stays at the bottom.

Comment: I'm happy to scroll to the bottom when new entries are added to the list.  But I don't think that 'workaround' achieves anything relevant to what I'm asking. I need a list that grows from the bottom up (rather than from the top growing down) and which allow for manual mouse scrolling at any time.  Whether the list scrolls to the bottom as new entries are made sounds off-topic to what I'm asking. Check out my jsfiddle link in my question and click on the 'both' link - notice how it doesn't scroll?  How do I make it scrollable?

Comment: check my edit above. I used scrollTop method to set the scroll bar position to bottom. See if it helps you.