# Clean code for finding the intersection of tuples in a list

Tags: math, functional-programming, set

I've written a algorithm to find parameters in a command line tool and are looking to clean up my code but is stuck.

#### The task

My program receives parameters as: `flag output input ...` | `input flag output`
Examples are: `-d one/path second/path/to/file.txt` and `second/path/to/file.txt --dir one/path` etc. Each space is used as a delimiter to create an array of parameters. A parameter can be either a *flag* such as `-d` or a *path*.

I got each flag mapped out in two arrays, which I zip into a an array of tuples. I call them the *search* set.

#### In math notation

I'm new to both FP and math notations so please forgive my mistakes (I've learned from wikipedia and other sites).

**S** for *search* and **P** for *parameters*

```
S = { S₁, S₂, S₃ }
where Sn = { flagShort, flagLong }
where flagShort = '-d' | '-r' | '-o'
      flagLong = '--dir' | '--replace' | '--output'

P = { P₁, P₂, ... }
where Pn = flag | path
where path = dir | file
```

So I need to find the *output* by searching P for occurrences of Sn + the next parameter after the *flag*.

```
Ps = Sn ∩ P + Pₙ+₁
```

*Input is just `Ps ∉ P`, so that is easy if I can get Ps.*

Which leads me to the following transformation:

```
P -> Pn -> S -> Sn -> Sn = Pn -> Pn + Pₙ+₁
```

In javascript it can be written as:

```
const flagsShort = ["-r","-d","-o"]
const flagsLong = ["--replace","--dir","--output"]
const search =  _.zip(flagsShort, flagsLong)

let Ps = tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP(
    ['one/path', '--dir', 'two/path', '-d', 'one/path', '-d'],
    search
)
// Ps -> [ '--dir', 'two/path', '-d', 'one/path' ]

function tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP(P, S) {
    const Ps = [];
    P.forEach(  (Pn, n) => {
        S.forEach(Sn => {
            Sn.forEach(flag => {
                if(flag===Pn) Ps.push(Pn, P[n+1])
            })
        })
    })
    return Ps
}
```

While the code above works, it doesn't look clean. I've been looking around for different FP libraries such as [underscore](http://devdocs.io/underscore) and different python articles but have yet to figure out how to use all these clever FP functions to clean up my code.

I will accept an answer in any language, Python, Haskell, Scala, etc but please don't use list comprehensions. While I'm very confident that I can port your code to js, I find list comprehensions a tad difficult to port. Better use `map` `each` `reduce` etc.

If you also can point me in the right direction with the set notations, I will be truly grateful!

Comment: can I ask you a question regarding this answer of yours please: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21067431/4828463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disclaimer

*I tend to stay away from Javascript. There might be nicer ways to do certain things in Javascript, but I believe that the general principles still hold.*

Your code is fine, albeit nested a little deep.

The trick in making your code cleaner is to extract abstract functionality. In the deepest nesting, what you're really asking is "*does element `Pn` exist in the list of lists `S`?*" This is something I can imagine myself asking more than once in an application, so it's perfect to turn into a function. You could even make this recursive for any level of nesting:

```
function ElementInNestedLists(e, l) {
    if (l instanceof Array) {
        return l.reduce(function(prev, cur, idx, arr) {
            if (prev || ElementInNestedLists(e, cur)) { 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }, false);
    } else {
        return l == e;
    }
}
```

You don't have to use `reduce` here. There's nothing forbidding you from doing an actual `for`-loop in functional programming, in languages that support it.  This does a better job at preventing the function from continuing after your element has been found:

```
function ElementInNestedLists(e, l) {
    if (l instanceof Array) {
        for (elem of l) {
            if (ElementInNestedLists(e, elem)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return l == e;
    }
}
```

Using this new function, you can simplify `tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP`:

```
function tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP(P, S) {
    const Ps = [];
    P.forEach(  (Pn, n) => {
        if (ElementInNestedLists(Pn, S)) {
            Ps.push(Pn, P[n + 1]);
        }
    });
    return Ps;
}
```

**But there's a bug**. The output of this function, given your input, is `[ '--dir', 'two/path', '-d', 'one/path', _undefined_ ]`, because the last flag has no parameter following it. We need to add a test to ensure that there are at least two elements remaining to be checked.

```
function tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP(P, S) {
    const Ps = [];
    P.forEach(  (Pn, n) => {
        if (n + 1 < P.length && ElementInNestedLists(Pn, S)) {
            Ps.push(Pn, P[n + 1]);
        }
    });
    return Ps;
}
```

**But there's another bug**. Consider the input `['-d', '-d', 'foo']`. The output would be `['-d', '-d', '-d', 'foo']`, which is incorrect.  The desired output is `['-d', '-d']`. You could decide to add a variable to track whether or not you need to process the next field:

```
function tuplesIntersectionParametersPlusNextP(P, S) {
    const Ps = [];
    skip = false;
    P.forEach(  (Pn, n) => {
        if (skip) {
            skip = false;
            return;
        }
        if (n+1 < P.length && ElementInNestedLists(Pn, S)) {
            Ps.push(Pn, P[n + 1]);
            skip = true;
        }
    })
    return Ps
}
```

And while this does what you want, you've now lost cleanliness again. The solution (as is often the case in functional programming) is to solve this problem recursively.

```
function Parse(cmd, flags, acc = []) {
    if (cmd.length < 2) {
        return acc;
    }
    
    if (ElementInNestedLists(cmd[0], flags)) {
        acc.push(cmd[0], cmd[1]);
        return Parse(cmd.slice(2, cmd.length), flags, acc)
    }
    return Parse(cmd.slice(1, cmd.length), flags, acc)
}
```

And if you don't want to slice:

```
function Parse(cmd, flags, idx = 0, acc = []) {
    if (idx + 1 >= cmd.length) {
        return acc;
    }
    
    if (ElementInNestedLists(cmd[idx], flags)) {
        acc.push(cmd[idx], cmd[idx + 1]);
        return Parse(cmd, flags, idx + 2, acc);
    }
    return Parse(cmd, flags, idx + 1, acc);
}
```

Of course, you might want to check and discard — or otherwise handle — a flag following a flag. There might be other, more complex requirements that you either haven't mentioned or haven't thought of (yet), but those are outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: nice! I couldn't figure out how to do it recursively. Your steps was very educational. The reason I want to capture invalid flags, is that I want to throw descriptive errors and to that end, I need to know what the user did wrong.