# Automatic scroll down to bottom of result in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to configure the ipython notebook so that whenever I print a long list, I automatically see the bottom?

for example, in the terminal, if I run the following:

```
for i in range(1000):
  print i
```

It automatically scrolls to the bottom:

```
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
999

In [2]:
```

But in the Python notebook, I see the beginning and I have to manually scroll down to the last numbers.

I am running a long loop that takes a few seconds for each iteration, and it is inconvenient to have to scroll down whenever I want to check how far along the program is,

thank you,

Comment: Not a quick fix, but you could "theme" the python notebook template to include this functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up

Answer (score 14):

Recommend:
[Tampermonkey plugin](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/418158-jupyter-notebook-auto-scroll)

(Once for all action!)
Copy & paste the following codes to any cell (or console,F12), run it.
After execution, you can delete the cell, then just continue your work!

```
%%javascript

window.scroll_flag = true
window.scroll_exit = false
window.scroll_delay = 100

$(".output_scroll").each(function() {
    $(this)[0].scrollTop = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
});

function callScrollToBottom() {
    setTimeout(scrollToBottom, window.scroll_delay);
}

function scrollToBottom() {
    if (window.scroll_exit) {
        return;
    }
    if (!window.scroll_flag) {
        callScrollToBottom();
        return;
    };
    
    $(".output_scroll").each(function() {
        if (!$(this).attr('scroll_checkbox')){
            window.scroll_flag = true;
            $(this).attr('scroll_checkbox',true);
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.onclick = function(){window.scroll_flag = checkbox.checked}
            checkbox.checked = "checked"
            div.append("Auto-Scroll-To-Bottom: ");
            div.append(checkbox);
            $(this).parent().before(div);
        }
        
        $(this)[0].scrollTop = $(this)[0].scrollHeight;
    });
    callScrollToBottom();
}
scrollToBottom();
```

Or you can try [jupyter_contrib_nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions)'s 'scroll-down' plugin, however, it's not quite user-friendly, compare to my little script.

Comment: Javascript Error: $ is not defined

Comment: @user2809176 use the recommend way

Answer (score 1):

I use jupyter-notebook alot and didnt like that it didnt auto scroll to the bottom, so what I use is **progressbar2**, then you can do something like:

```py
import progressbar
with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=1000) as bar:
    for idx, val in enumerate(range(1000)):
        bar.update(idx)
```

Then you will see one line output with more useful info like percentage complete, elapsed time, ETA,::

```
100% (1000 of 1000) |####################| Elapsed Time: 0:00:00 Time:  0:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but there is an extension in Jupyter Notebook called [ScrollDown](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/scroll_down/readme.html).

> When enabled, this nbextension scrolls cells’ outputs down automatically as they are enlarged. It can be enabled and disabled using the toolbar button

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a way to do this with iPython, however, if you use Pandas, you can use the [tail](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) function to print only the last records.

You can even import your data into Pandas from Python native tuples:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(range(1000), columns = (id,))
```

**If you don't want to use Pandas,** you can collect all items into a list and then only print the last 10 records:

```
print(list(range(1000))[-10])
```