# In Jupyter notebook, can the "enable scrolling" window auto-scroll down to keep up pace with the output?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I often write functions that print a lot, say every 100th go-around a long loop, which in the Terminal run fine, because my screen auto-scrolls down with the output; but on Jupyter, the output quickly moves downward, and I have to scroll down myself to keep up with it. This happens whether I'm in the "enable scrolling" or "disable scrolling" for the output.

So, my Q is: Is there a way to have Jupyter auto-scroll down with the output? I suppose this would make more sense inside of a scroll window (i.e. "enable scrolling".) Auto-scrolled output would give a more Terminal-like experience, which I am much more familiar and comfortable with. (And, to be honest, I also miss my The-Matrix-like aesthetic of streaming output.)

If it matters, I use Jupyter Lab primarily, but I believe the same is true on Jupyter Notebook.

Thanks so much, all!

Comment: It seems there is no proper way to do this at the moment as this question shows, but there are wonky workarounds depending on what you would like to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539841/automatic-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-result-in-ipython-notebook

Answer (score 1):

nbextensions has an auto-scroll extension to do just that, though its incompatible with jupyter lab at the moment.

https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/autoscroll/README.html