# JQuery - Scroll and anchor to bottom of ajax-driven div unless user scrolls up with demo code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to scroll to the bottom of a div #chat-feed with overflow set to auto and stay there unless a user scrolls that div's content up. If they scroll back down, the div should lock to the bottom and new content will be displayed at the bottom.

**Note:** This will be read only. There will be no "add test message" or any button or text input on the final version. This will allow spectators the ability to watch the chat feed live.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class='doesntSupportFlex'>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#chat-feed {
    height: 203px; 
    width: 300px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
p.chat-feed {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="chat-feed"></div>
<br>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="button" name="chat-button" id="chat-button"  value="add test message" class="btn btn-info" />

    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chat-button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php",
        });
    });

    // Initial load (without this there will be a delay of loaded content)
    $('#chat-feed').load("chat-feed.php");
    var out = document.getElementById("chat-feed"); // outer container of messages

    // generate some chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {


        //check current scroll position BEFORE message is appended to the container
        var isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();

        $('#chat-feed').load("chat-feed.php");

        // scroll to bottom if scroll position had been at bottom prior
        scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }
    setTimeout(function() { $("#chat-feed").scrollTop($("#chat-feed")[0].scrollHeight);}, 1200);
});
</script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `$('#chat_button)` code, no problem, but keep the rest of it as is.

The key here is to detect whether scrolled bottom, then load more content, then reposition the scroll if previously at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var out, isScrolledToBottom;

    out = document.getElementById("chat-feed"); // outer container of messages

    $('#chat_button').click(function(){
        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();

        $.ajax({
            url:"insert.php"
        }).done(function() {
            scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        });
    });

    // initial load of chat
    $('#chat-feed').load("chat-feed.php", function() {
      out = document.getElementById("chat-feed"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
      scrollToBottom(true);
    });


    // check for chatter every second
    setInterval(function() {

        isScrolledToBottom = checkIfScrolledBottom();

        $('#chat-feed').load("chat-feed.php", function() {
          out = document.getElementById("chat-feed"); // re-reference after a jQuery .load() as it removes the original dom element and add a new one
          scrollToBottom(isScrolledToBottom);
        });

    }, 1000);

    function checkIfScrolledBottom() {
        // allow for 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
        return out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    }

    function scrollToBottom(scrollDown) {
        if (scrollDown)
        out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }
    //setTimeout(function() { $("#chat-feed").scrollTop($("#chat-feed")[0].scrollHeight);}, 1200);
});
```

Comment: The [demo page](http://dev.zerosurvival.com/_finished_tests/ajax_feed/index.php) is updated but something appears to be broken as it is not inserting data through AJAX. I inserted data manually and it loaded into the `#chat-feed` container but it did not maintain the bottom scroll position.

Comment: There was a typo - a stray comma (`url:"insert.php",`). Please try again

Comment: Updated. It is still not inserting and manually inserting still does not respect scroll position.

Comment: I've refreshed the demo and that stray comma is still there, please copy and paste the code above

Comment: The answer is still showing the original code, however, I have manually removed the comma from `url:"insert.php",`. Still having the same issue.

Comment: insert.php returns nothing http://dev.zerosurvival.com/_finished_tests/ajax_feed/insert.php

Comment: That is correct. The page just has to load for a new demo message to be inserted. There is no return and no output. It is simply a trigger to insert fake chat messages for testing. Reload that page and you can see more messages have been added to the demo container.

Comment: Also `$.ajax({url:"insert.php",});` by itself does nothing. You have to do something with the returned results - either append to the existing chat, or alertnatively use `.load` if you're getting all chat in one go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137600/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-damien).

Comment: A question for you, do you get notified when a new answer is posted?  I haven't posted a question in a long time so can't remember if that happens or not

Comment: I dont get notified. I just see a new red icon at the top of the site when I visit. That is why it may take me some time to reply.