# Problems using SO answer of staying scrolled to the bottom when new content appears at the bottom of the overflow div

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I've been using the top two answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up) and I can't get it to work.

Here is my code

```
$(function(){

// Now let's load our messages
function load_messages(){
    $( "#chatscreen" ).append( "<br>Test" );
}

var out = document.getElementById("chatscreen");
var c = 0;
var add = setInterval(function() {
    // allow 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
    var isScrolledToBottom = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    //console.log(out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight,  out.scrollTop + 1);
    var newElement = document.createElement("div");

    newElement.innerHTML = c++;
    out.appendChild(newElement);

    // scroll to bottom if isScrolledToBotto
    if(isScrolledToBottom) {out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight; }
}, 1000);

setInterval(load_messages,300); // change to 300 to show the latest message you sent after pressing enter // comment this line and it works, uncomment and it fails
                                // leaving it on 1000 shows the second to last message
setInterval(updateScroll,30);
});
```

The purpose of the `load_messages` function is to add new messages in the chat room that have been posted, to the `#chatscreen` div every 300 milliseconds.

The scrollbar does not stay at the bottom of the div when `load_messages` appends the div with a new message.

Comment: I paid people $40 to solve this for me and I got three working solutions, some better than others.

Comment: I used Reddit r/forhire and Upwork.