# Scrollbar focus on the bottom of the HTML div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do I make this scrollbar focus on the bottom of this div. Does JavaScript is necessary?

[image: Simple chat box]

Comment: Here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div
       (and)  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep overflow div scrolled to bottom unless user scrolls up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("divname").animate({ scrollTop: $('divname').prop("scrollHeight")}, 0);
```

Does require Jquery

Answer (score 0):

nice and simple just put this code somewhere in your script, preferably the top

```
     <script>
     var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
     if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
     objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

      window.history.replaceState( null, null, 
      window.location.href );
      }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Example:

```
document.getElementById('your_div').scrollIntoView()
```

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById("my_div").scrollIntoView();
```

```css
.page-body {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-body">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p id="my_div">lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```