# Chat does not scroll to the bottom when I use Jquery Load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

Chat does not scroll to bottom after jquery load method

My chat works by load new messages inside a scrolling div with `jquery load method` but div do not scroll to bottom when new messages are loaded, also I can't run `out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight`; with the div load because as it loads every second when user click scroll to older messages it just make the scroll control flash all the time.

I am using this example of this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/KpM5j/
It all looks to work fine but it's not working when I use with `jquery .load()` method 
my **index.php**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  setInterval(
    function() {
      $('#out').load('load_chat.php');
      var messageBody = document.querySelector('#out');
      out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
    }, 3000);
</script>

<script>
  var out = document.getElementById("out");
  var c = 0;
  var add = setInterval(function() {
    // allow 1px inaccuracy by adding 1
    var isScrolledToBottom = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight <= out.scrollTop + 1;
    console.log(out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight, out.scrollTop + 1);
    var newElement = document.createElement("div");
    newElement.innerHTML = c++;
    out.appendChild(newElement);
    // scroll to bottom if isScrolledToBotto
    if (isScrolledToBottom)
      out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
  }, 1000);
</script>

<div id="out" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:80px;"></div>
```

I need to load the  **load_chat.php** and also keep the page scrolling to the bottom 
I can't use

```
var out = document.getElementById('out');
out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight;
```

inside the load by Interval function, because it makes scrolling very weird, can someone help?

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question and explain us how your chat works? It's not like I don't want to help you, but it seems to me your approach here is completely wrong. So I'd like to be sure before I actually give you advise that will be helpful to you :)

Comment: it works by load new messages inside a scrolling div with jquery load method but div do not scroll to bottom when new messages are loaded, also I can't run `out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight;` with the div load because as it loads every second when user click scroll to older messages it just make the scroll controll flash all time time

Comment: Yes and that's exactly your problem here. You are using `load()` which is basicly just Ajax. If done right, it'll work. But you'll soon run into way more issues than that. Ajax was never ment to be used for chatsystems. It's way too heavy on your server. As soon as you get around 10 chatters online, your entire server will just hang and nearly give up. Especially since I assume you're constantly querying your database here for all the messages

Comment: Instead, you should be using websockets. You'll be able to support hundreds, perhaps even thousends of users online at the same time. It's way faster and leightweight. A good place to start would be at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). They even have a tutorial on how to setup a basic chat. And, websockets don't require page refreshes or ajax to load the data :)

Comment: I used websockers with rachet but It need to keep an open server renning file other wise chat do not work , do you know how avoid it?

Comment: The server file is ment to run through cli (command line interface). Not as a normal website. So if your server runs on Linux, login through SSH and run it from there or create a cron job in your server admin panel. If it runs on Windows, just run a command prompt.

Comment: it's a good alternative but not good as a production ready solution

Comment: No the tutorial is not ment the be used as a production ready solution. You're supposed to program that yourself. But the library on its own is very much ready. Chatsystems are fun projects that you can learn a lot from. But they're not for beginner programmers. They can and will become extremely complicated very fast. Think about private chat, blocking users, kicking, banning, adding friends.. the list goes on and on

Comment: do you reccomend also I check webrtc? it's better than websockets?

Comment: No WebRTC is basicly making browser to browser connections between clients. It might work, but you wouldn't have any control over it at all. Your server basicly establishes the connections, but after that it's no longer involved in it. The data will not go through your server, just directly between clients. Hence WebRTC is more interesting for one-on-one audio / video calls than chat systems.

Comment: I don't understand why websockets are such an issue for you? The only reason you wouldn't be able to use them is if you hired a very cheap server and aren't able to run the server part 24/7 because of no cli access / cron jobs available. In which case running a chatsystem might not be the best choice at all. Such servers simply do not have the capacity to run services that are high demanding.

Comment: First of all, you have 2 timers (`setInterval`). The first timer, that loads content, runs every 3 seconds and the second timer, that add an (_dummy_) element and check for scroll position, is run every second. The logic of this, just does not make sense. You want to load content periodically, **not** insert _dummy_ elements. In order to help you, it would very useful to see the client-side output of **load_chat.php**.
The only thing I can say at the moment is that you **need to have only 1 timer**.