# Server side rendered element should be scrolled to bottom on initial render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, browser, scroll

I’m building a React server side rendered application (Next.js) and have a scrollable `<div>` that I want to be scrolled to the bottom on initial load of the page before React has hydrated the component.

That means a `useLayoutEffect()` hook like the following is not sufficient because there will be a brief flash of the element scrolled to the top before React mounts and runs this hook.

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const element = ref.current;
  element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
});
```

The approach that I think will work to prevent this is adding a `<script>` tag in the server side rendered page. For example:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}>
        ...
      </div>
      <script>
        var element = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling;
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
      </script>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, I’ve found that when the `<script>` executes the `clientHeight` of the `<div>` element is 0.

Presumably, I need to wait for the browser to finish loading the DOM so I added a `DOMContentLoaded` listener:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}>
        ...
      </div>
      <script>
        var element = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling;
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
          element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
        });
      </script>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, with this approach it appears the browser still does a paint with `scrollTop` set to 0 and then processes the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

How can I write a `<script>` here that executes the “scroll to bottom” behavior *after* DOM properties like `element.clientHeight` have loaded but *before* the first browser paint so the user doesn’t see a flash of the wrong scroll position.

Is there a better approach than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version actually works in production. It doesn’t work in development because Next.js use’s Webpack’s `style-loader` in development which means styles don’t load until the JavaScript code has loaded and the JavaScript code is loaded at the end of the document `<body>`.

So in production `element.clientHeight` will be correct (since the CSS was loaded in the `<head>`) but in development `element.clientHeight` will be 0 (since the CSS will be loaded at the end of `<body>`).

```
function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{overflowY: "scroll"}}>
        ...
      </div>
      <script>
        var element = document.currentScript.previousElementSibling;
        element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
      </script>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for this:

You don't need to control scroll position on server side because you can set you overflowing div to be flex-direction: column-reverse and browser will make it bottom scrolled by default.

Relevant answer [Keep overflow div scrolled to bottom unless user scrolls up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up)