# Make contents of div scroll to bottom using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

Can anyone suggest a way to make the contents of a div (when they exceed the size of the div) to scroll to the bottom.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up#44051405) from Jim Hall as refined in comments you can do it by adding an extra div with the following:

```
display: flex; 
flex-direction: column-reverse
```

However, this is not working for me (contents just load scrolled to top with bottom content hidden.)

Here is my code:

CSS:

//The point of the next class is to force a scroll to the bottom but it is not working

```
.chatContainer {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.chatContents {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chatContainer">
<div class="chatContents">
<div id = "bubbles"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this in pure CSS or with simple javascript (no jquery etc.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting the size of the div which contains the chatbox kind of how i did in the following code:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("chatbox");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
```

```css
.chatContainer {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.chatContents {
  width: 300px;
  border: solid 1px #EEE;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 25vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatContainer">
  <div class="chatContents" id="chatbox">
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
        <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hello
    </div>
    <div id = "bubbles">
      hellodjfdjfhdjfhsdhskfhsdkhfsdkhfjsdhf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by limiting the height of the chatbox, you are stopping it from growing as the comment numbers increase :)

Comment: When I run the snippet, it scrolls to the top not the bottom.

Comment: I added some javascript. It should be scrolled to the bottom now. If you need it to update when a new comment is added I would follow the following post's javascript were I found this snip of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614301/keep-overflow-div-scrolled-to-bottom-unless-user-scrolls-up